# Writing python dict data to a .csv and correcting the formatting

Tags: python, csv

I am writing my `df` to a `.csv` file to load into Minitab.  However, I am currently doing a lot of post-manipulation of the `.csv` file in order to make it friendly for Minitab.  I would like to write my Python code to make it easier and quicker for me to already have it in the desired format.

**Currently:** `csv.writer`is currently writing the `.csv` to the following format:

[image]

**My objective:** is to write the csv in this format; (and to also change the periods to commas).

[image]

```
import csv
a_file = open("raw_data.csv", "w")


writer = csv.writer(a_file)
for key, value in df.items():
    writer.writerow([key, value])

a_file.close()
```

My `df`looks like the following:

`{'K': [77.92589285714281, 75.34811320754717, 77.68070175438596, 75.37850467289722, 79.62212389380527, 79.40999999999998, 79.3535714285714, 77.35833333333332, 79.21904761904761, 'Z': [76.04260869565215, 80.10176991150445, 76.62086956521739, 77.64473684210527, 79.50087719298244, 80.70350877192982, 78.92543859649123, 80.88198198198197, 78.96869565217392, 77.112389380531,}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are very close

```
import csv
a_file = open("raw_data.csv", "w")

writer = csv.writer(a_file)
for key, value in df.items():

    # value is a list, so you have to iterate through that
    for v in value:

        # you'd see this fix in a moment on your own 
        writer.writerow([value, key])

a_file.close()
```

I don't know how to do the decimal conversion off the top of my head, I'm sure it's "locale" related.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have all the values **inside** the key, you have to iterate again the values.
The code you must need looks like this:

```
import csv
a_file = open("raw_data.csv", "w")


writer = csv.writer(a_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for key, values in df.items():
    for value in values:
        writer.writerow([key, str(value).replace(".",",")])
```

The `quoting` dialet close all the values and keys in doublequotes, since you will use commas in the values you will need it(since the csv format works with commas), and the `str(value).replace(".",",")` just replace the periods with commas